# Simple C++ circular queue

Tags: c++, collections, circular-list

I wrote a simple C++20 circular queue.
https://github.com/torrentg/cqueue

Here is cqueue.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <concepts>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace gto {

/**
 * @brief Circular queue.
 * @details Iterators are invalidated by: push(), push_front(), emplace(), pop(), pop_back(), reset() and clear().
 * @see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer
 * @see https://github.com/torrentg/cqueue
 * @note This class is not thread-safe.
 * @version 1.0.0
 */
template<std::semiregular T>
class cqueue {

  public: // declarations

    //! cqueue iterator.
    class iterator {
      public:
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = T *;
        using reference = T &;
      private:
        cqueue<T> *queue = nullptr;
        difference_type pos = 0;
      private:
        std::size_t cast(difference_type n) const { return (n < 0 ? queue->size() : static_cast<std::size_t>(n)); }
        difference_type size() const { return static_cast<difference_type>(queue->size()); }
      public:
        explicit iterator(cqueue<T> *o, difference_type p = 0) : queue(o), pos(p < 0 ? -1 : (p < size() ? p : size())) {}
        reference operator*() { return queue->operator[](cast(pos)); }
        pointer operator->() { return &(queue->operator[](cast(pos))); }
        reference operator[](difference_type rhs) const { return (queue->operator[](cast(pos + rhs))); }
        bool operator==(const iterator &rhs) const { return (queue == rhs.queue && pos == rhs.pos); }
        bool operator!=(const iterator &rhs) const { return (queue != rhs.queue || pos != rhs.pos); }
        bool operator >(const iterator &rhs) const { return (queue == rhs.queue && pos  > rhs.pos); }
        bool operator <(const iterator &rhs) const { return (queue == rhs.queue && pos  < rhs.pos); }
        bool operator>=(const iterator &rhs) const { return (queue == rhs.queue && pos >= rhs.pos); }
        bool operator<=(const iterator &rhs) const { return (queue == rhs.queue && pos <= rhs.pos); }
        iterator& operator++() { pos = (pos + 1 < size() ? pos + 1 : size()); return *this; }
        iterator& operator--() { pos = (pos < 0 ? -1 : pos -1); return *this; }
        iterator  operator++(int) { iterator tmp(queue, pos); operator++(); return tmp; }
        iterator  operator--(int) { iterator tmp(queue, pos); operator--(); return tmp; }
        iterator& operator+=(difference_type rhs) { pos = (pos + rhs < size() ? pos + rhs : size()); return *this; }
        iterator& operator-=(difference_type rhs) { pos = (pos - rhs < 0 ? -1 : pos - rhs); return *this; }
        iterator  operator+(difference_type rhs) const { return iterator(queue, pos + rhs); }
        iterator  operator-(difference_type rhs) const { return iterator(queue, pos - rhs); }
        friend iterator operator+(difference_type lhs, const iterator &rhs) { return iterator(rhs.queue, lhs + rhs.pos); }
        friend iterator operator-(difference_type lhs, const iterator &rhs) { return iterator(rhs.queue, lhs - rhs.pos); }
        difference_type operator-(const iterator &rhs) const { return (pos - rhs.pos); }
    };

    //! cqueue const iterator.
    class const_iterator {
      public:
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = const T;
        using pointer = const T *;
        using reference = const T &;
      private:
        const cqueue<T> *queue = nullptr;
        difference_type pos = 0;
      private:
        std::size_t cast(difference_type n) const { return (n < 0 ? queue->size() : static_cast<std::size_t>(n)); }
        difference_type size() const { return static_cast<difference_type>(queue->size()); }
      public:
        explicit const_iterator(const cqueue<T> *o, difference_type p = 0) : queue(o), pos(p < 0 ? -1 : (p < size() ? p : size())) {}
        reference operator*() { return queue->operator[](cast(pos)); }
        pointer operator->() { return &(queue->operator[](cast(pos))); }
        reference operator[](difference_type rhs) const { return (queue->operator[](cast(pos + rhs))); }
        bool operator==(const const_iterator &rhs) const { return (queue == rhs.queue && pos == rhs.pos); }
        bool operator!=(const const_iterator &rhs) const { return (queue != rhs.queue || pos != rhs.pos); }
        bool operator >(const const_iterator &rhs) const { return (queue == rhs.queue && pos  > rhs.pos); }
        bool operator <(const const_iterator &rhs) const { return (queue == rhs.queue && pos  < rhs.pos); }
        bool operator>=(const const_iterator &rhs) const { return (queue == rhs.queue && pos >= rhs.pos); }
        bool operator<=(const const_iterator &rhs) const { return (queue == rhs.queue && pos <= rhs.pos); }
        const_iterator& operator++() { pos = (pos + 1 < size() ? pos + 1 : size()); return *this; }
        const_iterator& operator--() { pos = (pos < 0 ? -1 : pos -1); return *this; }
        const_iterator  operator++(int) { const_iterator tmp(queue, pos); operator++(); return tmp; }
        const_iterator  operator--(int) { const_iterator tmp(queue, pos); operator--(); return tmp; }
        const_iterator& operator+=(difference_type rhs) { pos = (pos + rhs < size() ? pos + rhs : size()); return *this; }
        const_iterator& operator-=(difference_type rhs) { pos = (pos - rhs < 0 ? -1 : pos - rhs); return *this; }
        const_iterator  operator+(difference_type rhs) const { return const_iterator(queue, pos + rhs); }
        const_iterator  operator-(difference_type rhs) const { return const_iterator(queue, pos - rhs); }
        friend const_iterator operator+(difference_type lhs, const const_iterator &rhs) { return const_iterator(rhs.queue, lhs + rhs.pos); }
        friend const_iterator operator-(difference_type lhs, const const_iterator &rhs) { return const_iterator(rhs.queue, lhs - rhs.pos); }
        difference_type operator-(const const_iterator &rhs) const { return (pos - rhs.pos); }
    };

  private: // static members

    //! Capacity increase factor.
    static constexpr std::size_t GROWTH_FACTOR = 2;
    //! Default initial capacity (power of 2).
    static constexpr std::size_t DEFAULT_RESERVED = 8;
    //! Max capacity (user-defined power of 2).
    static constexpr std::size_t MAX_CAPACITY = 67'108'864;

  private: // members

    //! Buffer.
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> mData;
    //! Buffer size.
    std::size_t mReserved = 0;
    //! Maximum number of elements (always > 0).
    std::size_t mCapacity = 0;
    //! Index representing first entry (0 <= mFront < mReserved).
    std::size_t mFront = 0;
    //! Number of entries in the queue (empty = 0, full = mReserved).
    std::size_t mLength = 0;

  private: // methods

    //! Convert from pos to index (throw exception if out-of-bounds).
    std::size_t getCheckedIndex(std::size_t pos) const noexcept(false);
    //! Convert from pos to index.
    std::size_t getUncheckedIndex(std::size_t pos) const noexcept;
    //! Compute memory size to reserve.
    std::size_t getNewMemoryLength(std::size_t n) const;
    //! Ensure buffer size.
    void reserve(std::size_t n);

  public: // static methods

    //! Maximum capacity the container is able to hold.
    static std::size_t max_capacity() noexcept { return MAX_CAPACITY; }

  public: // methods

    //! Constructor (0 means unlimited).
    cqueue(std::size_t capacity = 0);
    //! Copy constructor.
    cqueue(const cqueue &other);
    //! Move constructor.
    cqueue(cqueue &&other) noexcept { this->swap(other); }
    //! Destructor.
    ~cqueue() = default;

    //! Copy assignment.
    cqueue & operator=(const cqueue &other);
    //! Move assignment.
    cqueue & operator=(cqueue &&other) { this->swap(other); return *this; }

    //! Return queue capacity.
    std::size_t capacity() const { return (mCapacity == MAX_CAPACITY ? 0 : mCapacity); }
    //! Return the number of items.
    std::size_t size() const { return mLength; }
    //! Current reserved size (numbers of items).
    std::size_t reserved() const { return mReserved; }
    //! Check if there are items in the queue.
    bool empty() const { return (mLength == 0); }

    //! Return the first element.
    const T & front() const { return operator[](0); }
    //! Return the first element.
    T & front() { return operator[](0); }
    //! Return the last element.
    const T & back() const { return operator[](mLength-1); }
    //! Return the last element.
    T & back() { return operator[](mLength-1); }

    //! Insert an element at the end.
    void push(const T &val);
    //! Insert an element at the end.
    void push(T &&val);
    //! Insert an element at the front.
    void push_front(const T &val);
    //! Insert an element at the front.
    void push_front(T &&val);

    //! Construct and insert an element at the end.
    template <class... Args>
    void emplace(Args&&... args);
    //! Remove the front element.
    bool pop();
    //! Remove the back element.
    bool pop_back();

    //! Returns a reference to the element at position n.
    T & operator[](std::size_t n) { return mData[getCheckedIndex(n)]; }
    //! Returns a const reference to the element at position n.
    const T & operator[](std::size_t n) const { return mData[getCheckedIndex(n)]; }

    //! Returns an iterator to the first element.
    iterator begin() noexcept { return iterator(this, 0); }
    //! Returns an iterator to the element following the last element.
    iterator end() noexcept { return iterator(this, static_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(size())); }
    //! Returns an iterator to the first element.
    const_iterator begin() const noexcept { return const_iterator(this, 0); }
    //! Returns an iterator to the element following the last element.
    const_iterator end() const noexcept { return const_iterator(this, static_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(size())); }

    //! Clear content.
    void clear() noexcept;
    //! Swap content.
    void swap (cqueue<T> &x) noexcept;
};

} // namespace gto

/**
 * @param[in] capacity Container capacity.
 */
template<std::semiregular T>
gto::cqueue<T>::cqueue(std::size_t capacity) {
  if (capacity > MAX_CAPACITY) {
    throw std::length_error("cqueue max capacity exceeded");
  } else {
    mCapacity = (capacity == 0 ? MAX_CAPACITY : capacity);
  }
}

/**
 * @param[in] other Queue to copy.
 */
template<std::semiregular T>
gto::cqueue<T>::cqueue(const cqueue &other) {
  mCapacity = other.mCapacity;
  reserve(mLength);
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < other.size(); i++) {
    push(other[i]);
  }
}

/**
 * @param[in] other Queue to copy.
 */
template<std::semiregular T>
gto::cqueue<T> & gto::cqueue<T>::operator=(const cqueue &other) {
  clear();
  mCapacity = other.mCapacity;
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < other.size(); i++) {
    push(other[i]);
  }
  return *this;
}

/**
 * @param[in] num Element position.
 * @return Index in buffer.
 */
template<std::semiregular T>
std::size_t gto::cqueue<T>::getUncheckedIndex(std::size_t pos) const noexcept {
  return (mFront + pos) % (mReserved == 0 ? 1 : mReserved);
}

/**
 * @param[in] num Element position.
 * @return Index in buffer.
 * @exception std::out_of_range Invalid position.
 */
template<std::semiregular T>
std::size_t gto::cqueue<T>::getCheckedIndex(std::size_t pos) const noexcept(false) {
  if (pos >= mLength) {
    throw std::out_of_range("cqueue access out-of-range");
  } else {
    return getUncheckedIndex(pos);
  }
}

/**
 * @details Remove all elements.
 */
template<std::semiregular T>
void gto::cqueue<T>::clear() noexcept {
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < mLength; i++) {
    mData[getUncheckedIndex(i)] = T{};
  }
  mFront = 0;
  mLength = 0;
}

/**
 * @details Swap content with another same-type cqueue.
 */
template<std::semiregular T>
void gto::cqueue<T>::swap(cqueue<T> &x) noexcept {
  mData.swap(x.mData);
  std::swap(mFront, x.mFront);
  std::swap(mLength, x.mLength);
  std::swap(mReserved, x.mReserved);
  std::swap(mCapacity, x.mCapacity);
}

/**
 * @brief Compute the new buffer size.
 * @param[in] n New queue size.
 */
template<std::semiregular T>
std::size_t gto::cqueue<T>::getNewMemoryLength(std::size_t n) const {
  std::size_t ret = (mReserved == 0 ? std::min(mCapacity, DEFAULT_RESERVED) : mReserved);
  while (ret < n) {
    ret *= GROWTH_FACTOR;
  }
  return std::min(ret, mCapacity);
}

/**
 * @param[in] n Expected future queue size.
 * @exception std::length_error Capacity exceeded.
 */
template<std::semiregular T>
void gto::cqueue<T>::reserve(std::size_t n) {
  if (n < mReserved) {
    return;
  } else if (n > mCapacity) {
    throw std::length_error("cqueue capacity exceeded");
  }

  std::size_t len = getNewMemoryLength(n);
  auto tmp = std::make_unique<T[]>(len);
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < mLength; i++) {
    tmp[i] = std::move(mData[getUncheckedIndex(i)]);
  }

  mReserved = len;
  mData.swap(tmp);
  mFront = 0;
}

/**
 * @param[in] val Value to add.
 * @exception std::length_error Number of values exceed queue capacity.
 */
template<std::semiregular T>
void gto::cqueue<T>::push(const T &val) {
  reserve(mLength + 1);
  mData[getUncheckedIndex(mLength)] = val;
  mLength++;
}

/**
 * @param[in] val Value to add.
 * @exception std::length_error Number of values exceed queue capacity.
 */
template<std::semiregular T>
void gto::cqueue<T>::push(T &&val) {
  reserve(mLength + 1);
  mData[getUncheckedIndex(mLength)] = std::move(val);
  mLength++;
}

/**
 * @param[in] val Value to add.
 * @exception std::length_error Number of values exceed queue capacity.
 */
template<std::semiregular T>
void gto::cqueue<T>::push_front(const T &val) {
  reserve(mLength + 1);
  mFront = (mLength == 0 ? 0 : (mFront == 0 ? mReserved : mFront) - 1);
  mData[mFront] = val;
  mLength++;
}

/**
 * @param[in] val Value to add.
 * @exception std::length_error Number of values exceed queue capacity.
 */
template<std::semiregular T>
void gto::cqueue<T>::push_front(T &&val) {
  reserve(mLength + 1);
  mFront = (mLength == 0 ? 0 : (mFront == 0 ? mReserved : mFront) - 1);
  mData[mFront] = std::move(val);
  mLength++;
}

/**
 * @param[in] args Arguments of the new item.
 * @exception std::length_error Number of values exceed queue capacity.
 */
template<std::semiregular T>
template <class... Args>
void gto::cqueue<T>::emplace(Args&&... args) {
  reserve(mLength + 1);
  mData[getUncheckedIndex(mLength)] = T{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
  mLength++;
}

/**
 * @return true = an element was erased, false = no elements in the queue.
 */
template<std::semiregular T>
bool gto::cqueue<T>::pop() {
  if (mLength == 0) {
    return false;
  }
  
  mData[mFront] = T{};
  mFront = getUncheckedIndex(1);
  mLength--;
  return true;
}

/**
 * @return true = an element was erased, false = no elements in the queue.
 */
template<std::semiregular T>
bool gto::cqueue<T>::pop_back() {
  if (mLength == 0) {
    return false;
  }
  mLength--;
  mData[getUncheckedIndex(mLength)] = T{};
  return true;
}
```

Is there something wrong? What can be improved?
All ideas are welcome, I will be happy to know your opinions and objections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks quite good to me: a very complete interface, including iterators, matching the interface of STL containers quite closely, Doxygen documentation, lots of attention to details like `const`, move semantics, perfect forwarding and so on.

## Unnecessary limitations

Why is there a `MAX_CAPACITY`, and where does the number 67108864 come from? It doesn't make any sense to me. The actual memory used also scales with `sizeof(T)`, but the limitation you impose is only for the number of elements stored. I would remove this limitation completely.

## Consider using an STL container to manage storage

Instead of allocating memory yourself and dealing with resizing, contructing and destructing elements, leave this to an existing STL container. In particular, [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) is a good candidate for this, or perhaps [`std::queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue). Apart from you having to write less code, it also fixes some problems that you have in your code, for example:

## Your code default-constructs unused elements

When you call `std::make_unique<T[]>(len)`, it will default-construct `len` elements. That's very surprising, since the STL containers do not have this behaviour. And this can cause problems if `T`'s constructor has side-effects, and it prevents your code from compiling if `T` doesn't have a default constructor.

The usual way around this is to allocate raw memory, and then using [placement `new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) to construct elements inside that storage only when needed. But then you also have to remember to call the destructors, deal with alignment restrictions, and tip-toe around any potential problems with pointer conversions. It can all be done of course, but I would strongly recommend to use an appropriate existing container where possible.

## What if an exception is thrown when resizing the storage?

Consider that the assignment operator of `T` that is used inside `reserve()` could throw an exception. What if you were halfway moving from the old storage into the new storage? In your case, the program still is in a valid state, but now part of the elements in your circular queue have potentially unintented values. Ideally, your member functions would have a [strong exception guarantee](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/exceptions#Exception_safety): the contents of the container are exactly the same as they were before the call that threw an exception. This can be achieved by copying instead of moving (indeed, this is why `std::vector` requires that its value type is copyable), or by never having to move or copy elements around to begin with (which is the property that `std::deque` has).

## Naming

The name of the class is `cqueue`, but unless you know that this is a circular queue, it's hard to tell what the `c` stands for. Is it perhaps a "constant" queue (like constant iterators you get with `cbegin()` and `cend()`)? Maybe it's a queue that can interact with C code? Avoid this problem by naming it `circular_queue`.

One might also wonder what is so circular about this queue. Will you be able to iterate infinitely, repeatedly looping through all elements? Will you be able to push elements when the queue is already full, automatically replacing the oldest element? While the implementation is using a circular buffer, for the user of this class the only difference between this and a `std::queue` is that there is a hard limit on the size, and it will throw `std::length_error` when you try to go past that limit. I would make sure you describe the properties of your class in more detail in the Doxygen comments describing the class.

## Example implementation based on `std::queue`

Just to illustrate how much the code can be reduced by using an existing STL container, consider this which is based on the implementation of `std::queue`:

```
template<typename T, class Container = std::deque<T>>
class circular_queue {
public:
    // Member types
    using container_type = Container;
    using value_type = Container::value_type;
    using size_type = Container::size_type;
    using reference = Container::reference;
    using const_reference = Container::const_reference;
    using iterator = Container::iterator;
    using const_iterator = Container::const_iterator;

    // Constructors and assignment operators
    circular_queue(size_type capacity = 0): mCapacity(capacity) {}
    // That's it, rest is defaulted for us!

    // Element access
    reference front() { return mData.front(); }
    const_reference front() const { return mData.front(); }
    reference back() { return mData.back(); }
    const_reference back() const { return mData.back(); }
    reference at(size_type pos) { return mData.at(pos); }
    const_reference at(size_type pos) { return mData.at(pos); }
    reference operator[](size_type pos) { return mData[pos]; }
    const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const { return mData[pos]; }

    // Capacity
    size_type capacity() const { return mCapacity; }
    size_type size() const { return mData.size(); }
    bool empty() const { return mData.empty(); }

    // Modifiers
    void push(const value_type& value) {
        check_capacity();
        mData.push_back(value);
    }

    void push(value_type&& value) {
        check_capacity();
        mData.push_back(std::move(value));
    }

    template<class... Args>
    decltype(auto) emplace(Args&&... args) {
        check_capacity();
        return mData.emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    void pop() { mData.pop_front(); }
    void clear() { mData.clear(); }

    void swap(circular_queue& other) {
        using std::swap;
        swap(mData, other.mData);
        swap(mCapacity, other.mCapacity);
    }

    // Iterators
    iterator begin() { return mData.begin(); }
    const_iterator begin() const { return mData.begin(); }
    const_iterator cbegin() const { return mData.cbegin(); }
    iterator end() { return mData.end(); }
    const_iterator end() const { return mData.end(); }
    const_iterator cend() const { return mData.cend(); }

private:
    Container mData;
    std::size_t mCapacity;

    void check_capacity() {
        if (mCapacity == mData.size()) {
            throw std::length_error("circular_queue capacity exceeded");
        }
    }
};
```

You could probably even reduce it further by *inheriting* from `Container` instead of having it as a member.

## Think about `constexpr`, `[[nodiscard]]` and more `noexcept`

It's great to see `const` and `noexcept` being used, but it might also be possible to make things [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr), and since C++17 you can add attributes such as [`[[nodiscard]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard) to guard against incorrect use of your class. Consider for example that `empty()` should ideally be all those things:

```
[[nodiscard]] constexpr bool empty() const noexcept;
```

Of course, some of these things require more recent versions of the C++ standard, so if you want to be compatible with older versions you might not be able to use these yet.

Comment: Thank you very much for your code review. I appreciate really it. I try to solve the identified issues.

Comment: Personally, I think that `[[nodiscard]]` on functions such as `empty()` is overkill and just serves to clutter.  At a stretch, I could imagine someone reading that as a verb instead of `clear()`, but it seems unlikely.  I prefer to reserve the attribute for functions that are like `std::scanf()`, where important and unrecoverable information is returned.

Comment: @TobySpeight It's not just someone reading it as a verb, it could also be a typo that causes the result of `empty()` to be ignored. Since there is no reason why you would ever want to call `empty()` and not look at the result, I think this is actually the perfect candidate for `[[nodiscard]]`. I agree it does clutter, which is unfortunate. Perhaps it would be better if `[[nodiscard]]` was the default. Maybe [Herb Sutter will fix this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELeZAKCN4tY).