# A not so simple C++20 circular queue

Tags: collections, c++20, circular-list

This container reduces the number of memory allocations on queue-type operations (push + pop) compared to std::deque. Basic performance tests indicates a performance similar to std::deque where main cost is the calculation of index ((mFront+pos)%mReserved).

A [first review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/281005/simple-c-circular-queue) was done by [G.Sliepen](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/129343/g-sliepen). I tried to solve almost all reported issues and replaced the system-managed memory (based on std::unique_ptr) by a user-managed memory. The big game started. Playing with soap in the prison shower!

Great chances that mistakes or errors are presents in the code.
I will appreciate you comments and suggestions.

Here is cqueue.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <limits>
#include <utility>
#include <concepts>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace gto {

/**
 * @brief Circular queue.
 * @details Iterators are invalidated by: 
 *          push(), push_front(), emplace(), pop(), pop_back(), reserve(), 
 *          shrink_to_fit(), reset() and clear().
 * @see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer
 * @see https://github.com/torrentg/cqueue
 * @note This class is not thread-safe.
 * @version 1.0.0
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
class cqueue {

  public: // declarations

    // Aliases  
    using value_type = T;
    using reference = value_type &;
    using const_reference = const value_type &;
    using pointer = T *;
    using const_pointer = const pointer;
    using size_type = std::size_t;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using allocator_type = Allocator;
    using const_alloc_reference = const allocator_type &;

    //! cqueue iterator.
    class iterator {
      public:
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
        using value_type = T;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using pointer = value_type *;
        using reference = value_type &;
      private:
        cqueue *queue = nullptr;
        difference_type pos = 0;
      private:
        size_type cast(difference_type n) const { return (n < 0 ? queue->size() : static_cast<size_type>(n)); }
        difference_type size() const { return static_cast<difference_type>(queue->size()); }
      public:
        explicit iterator(cqueue *o, difference_type p = 0) : queue(o), pos(p < 0 ? -1 : (p < size() ? p : size())) {}
        reference operator*() { return queue->operator[](cast(pos)); }
        pointer operator->() { return &(queue->operator[](cast(pos))); }
        reference operator[](difference_type rhs) const { return (queue->operator[](cast(pos + rhs))); }
        bool operator==(const iterator &rhs) const { return (queue == rhs.queue && pos == rhs.pos); }
        bool operator!=(const iterator &rhs) const { return (queue != rhs.queue || pos != rhs.pos); }
        bool operator >(const iterator &rhs) const { return (queue == rhs.queue && pos  > rhs.pos); }
        bool operator <(const iterator &rhs) const { return (queue == rhs.queue && pos  < rhs.pos); }
        bool operator>=(const iterator &rhs) const { return (queue == rhs.queue && pos >= rhs.pos); }
        bool operator<=(const iterator &rhs) const { return (queue == rhs.queue && pos <= rhs.pos); }
        iterator& operator++() { pos = (pos + 1 < size() ? pos + 1 : size()); return *this; }
        iterator& operator--() { pos = (pos < 0 ? -1 : pos -1); return *this; }
        iterator  operator++(int) { iterator tmp(queue, pos); operator++(); return tmp; }
        iterator  operator--(int) { iterator tmp(queue, pos); operator--(); return tmp; }
        iterator& operator+=(difference_type rhs) { pos = (pos + rhs < size() ? pos + rhs : size()); return *this; }
        iterator& operator-=(difference_type rhs) { pos = (pos - rhs < 0 ? -1 : pos - rhs); return *this; }
        iterator  operator+(difference_type rhs) const { return iterator(queue, pos + rhs); }
        iterator  operator-(difference_type rhs) const { return iterator(queue, pos - rhs); }
        friend iterator operator+(difference_type lhs, const iterator &rhs) { return iterator(rhs.queue, lhs + rhs.pos); }
        friend iterator operator-(difference_type lhs, const iterator &rhs) { return iterator(rhs.queue, lhs - rhs.pos); }
        difference_type operator-(const iterator &rhs) const { return (pos - rhs.pos); }
    };

    //! cqueue const iterator.
    class const_iterator {
      public:
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
        using value_type = const T;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using pointer = value_type *;
        using reference = value_type &;
      private:
        const cqueue *queue = nullptr;
        difference_type pos = 0;
      private:
        size_type cast(difference_type n) const { return (n < 0 ? queue->size() : static_cast<size_type>(n)); }
        difference_type size() const { return static_cast<difference_type>(queue->size()); }
      public:
        explicit const_iterator(const cqueue *o, difference_type p = 0) : queue(o), pos(p < 0 ? -1 : (p < size() ? p : size())) {}
        reference operator*() { return queue->operator[](cast(pos)); }
        pointer operator->() { return &(queue->operator[](cast(pos))); }
        reference operator[](difference_type rhs) const { return (queue->operator[](cast(pos + rhs))); }
        bool operator==(const const_iterator &rhs) const { return (queue == rhs.queue && pos == rhs.pos); }
        bool operator!=(const const_iterator &rhs) const { return (queue != rhs.queue || pos != rhs.pos); }
        bool operator >(const const_iterator &rhs) const { return (queue == rhs.queue && pos  > rhs.pos); }
        bool operator <(const const_iterator &rhs) const { return (queue == rhs.queue && pos  < rhs.pos); }
        bool operator>=(const const_iterator &rhs) const { return (queue == rhs.queue && pos >= rhs.pos); }
        bool operator<=(const const_iterator &rhs) const { return (queue == rhs.queue && pos <= rhs.pos); }
        const_iterator& operator++() { pos = (pos + 1 < size() ? pos + 1 : size()); return *this; }
        const_iterator& operator--() { pos = (pos < 0 ? -1 : pos -1); return *this; }
        const_iterator  operator++(int) { const_iterator tmp(queue, pos); operator++(); return tmp; }
        const_iterator  operator--(int) { const_iterator tmp(queue, pos); operator--(); return tmp; }
        const_iterator& operator+=(difference_type rhs) { pos = (pos + rhs < size() ? pos + rhs : size()); return *this; }
        const_iterator& operator-=(difference_type rhs) { pos = (pos - rhs < 0 ? -1 : pos - rhs); return *this; }
        const_iterator  operator+(difference_type rhs) const { return const_iterator(queue, pos + rhs); }
        const_iterator  operator-(difference_type rhs) const { return const_iterator(queue, pos - rhs); }
        friend const_iterator operator+(difference_type lhs, const const_iterator &rhs) { return const_iterator(rhs.queue, lhs + rhs.pos); }
        friend const_iterator operator-(difference_type lhs, const const_iterator &rhs) { return const_iterator(rhs.queue, lhs - rhs.pos); }
        difference_type operator-(const const_iterator &rhs) const { return (pos - rhs.pos); }
    };

  private: // static members

    //! Capacity increase factor.
    static constexpr size_type GROWTH_FACTOR = 2;
    //! Default initial capacity (power of 2).
    static constexpr size_type DEFAULT_RESERVED = 8;

  private: // members

    //! Memory allocator.
    [[no_unique_address]]
    allocator_type mAllocator;
    //! Buffer.
    pointer mData = nullptr;
    //! Buffer size.
    size_type mReserved = 0;
    //! Maximum number of elements (always > 0).
    size_type mCapacity = 0;
    //! Index representing first entry (0 <= mFront < mReserved).
    size_type mFront = 0;
    //! Number of entries in the queue (empty = 0, full = mReserved).
    size_type mLength = 0;

  private: // methods

    //! Convert from pos to index (throw exception if out-of-bounds).
    constexpr size_type getCheckedIndex(size_type pos) const noexcept(false);
    //! Convert from pos to index.
    constexpr size_type getUncheckedIndex(size_type pos) const noexcept;
    //! Compute memory size to reserve.
    constexpr size_type getNewMemoryLength(size_type n) const noexcept;
    //! Resize buffer.
    constexpr void resizeIfRequired(size_type n);
    //! Resize buffer.
    void resize(size_type n);
    //! Clear and dealloc memory (preserve capacity and allocator).
    void reset() noexcept;

  public: // static methods

    //! Maximum capacity the container is able to hold.
    static constexpr size_type max_capacity() noexcept { return (std::numeric_limits<difference_type>::max()); }

  public: // methods

    //! Constructor.
    constexpr explicit cqueue(const_alloc_reference alloc = Allocator()) : cqueue(0, alloc) {}
    //! Constructor (capacity=0 means unlimited).
    constexpr explicit cqueue(size_type capacity, const_alloc_reference alloc = Allocator());
    //! Copy constructor.
    constexpr cqueue(const cqueue &other);
    //! Copy constructor with allocator.
    constexpr cqueue(const cqueue &other, const_alloc_reference alloc);
    //! Move constructor.
    constexpr cqueue(cqueue &&other) noexcept { this->swap(other); }
    //! Move constructor.
    constexpr cqueue(cqueue &&other, const_alloc_reference alloc);
    //! Destructor.
    ~cqueue() noexcept { reset(); };

    //! Copy assignment.
    constexpr cqueue & operator=(const cqueue &other);
    //! Move assignment.
    constexpr cqueue & operator=(cqueue &&other) { this->swap(other); return *this; }

    //! Return container allocator.
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr allocator_type get_allocator() const noexcept { return mAllocator; }
    //! Return queue capacity.
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr size_type capacity() const noexcept { return (mCapacity == max_capacity() ? 0 : mCapacity); }
    //! Return the number of items.
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr size_type size() const noexcept { return mLength; }
    //! Current reserved size (numbers of items).
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr size_type reserved() const noexcept { return mReserved; }
    //! Check if there are items in the queue.
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr bool empty() const noexcept { return (mLength == 0); }

    //! Return the first element.
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr const_reference front() const { return operator[](0); }
    //! Return the first element.
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr reference front() { return operator[](0); }
    //! Return the last element.
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr const_reference back() const { return operator[](mLength-1); }
    //! Return the last element.
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr reference back() { return operator[](mLength-1); }

    //! Insert an element at the end.
    constexpr void push(const T &val);
    //! Insert an element at the end.
    constexpr void push(T &&val);
    //! Insert an element at the front.
    constexpr void push_front(const T &val);
    //! Insert an element at the front.
    constexpr void push_front(T &&val);

    //! Construct and insert an element at the end.
    template <class... Args>
    constexpr void emplace(Args&&... args);
    //! Remove the front element.
    constexpr bool pop();
    //! Remove the back element.
    constexpr bool pop_back();

    //! Returns a reference to the element at position n.
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr reference operator[](size_type n) { return mData[getCheckedIndex(n)]; }
    //! Returns a const reference to the element at position n.
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr const_reference operator[](size_type n) const { return mData[getCheckedIndex(n)]; }

    //! Returns an iterator to the first element.
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr iterator begin() noexcept { return iterator(this, 0); }
    //! Returns an iterator to the element following the last element.
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr iterator end() noexcept { return iterator(this, static_cast<difference_type>(size())); }
    //! Returns an iterator to the first element.
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr const_iterator begin() const noexcept { return const_iterator(this, 0); }
    //! Returns an iterator to the element following the last element.
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr const_iterator end() const noexcept { return const_iterator(this, static_cast<difference_type>(size())); }

    //! Clear content.
    void clear() noexcept;
    //! Swap content.
    constexpr void swap (cqueue &x) noexcept;
    //! Ensure buffer size.
    constexpr void reserve(size_type n);
    //! Shrink reserved memory to current size.
    constexpr void shrink_to_fit();
};

} // namespace gto

/**
 * @param[in] capacity Container capacity.
 * @param[in] alloc Allocator to use.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::cqueue(size_type capacity, const_alloc_reference alloc) : 
    mAllocator(alloc), mData{nullptr}, mReserved{0}, mCapacity{max_capacity()}, mFront{0}, mLength{0}
{
  if (capacity > max_capacity()) {
    throw std::length_error("cqueue max capacity exceeded");
  } else {
    mCapacity = (capacity == 0 ? max_capacity() : capacity);
  }
}

/**
 * @param[in] other Queue to copy.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::cqueue(const cqueue &other) :
    mAllocator{std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::select_on_container_copy_construction(other.get_allocator())},
    mData{nullptr}, mReserved{0}, mCapacity{other.mCapacity}, mFront{0}, mLength{0}
{
  resizeIfRequired(other.mLength);
  for (size_type i = 0; i < other.size(); ++i) {
    push(other[i]);
  }
}

/**
 * @param[in] other Queue to copy.
 * @param[in] alloc Allocator to use.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::cqueue(const cqueue &other, const_alloc_reference alloc) : 
    mAllocator{alloc}, mData{nullptr}, mReserved{0}, mCapacity{other.mCapacity}, mFront{0}, mLength{0}
{
  resizeIfRequired(other.mLength);
  for (size_type i = 0; i < other.size(); ++i) {
    push(other[i]);
  }
}

/**
 * @param[in] other Queue to copy.
 * @param[in] alloc Allocator to use
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::cqueue(cqueue &&other, const_alloc_reference alloc) :
    mData{nullptr}, mReserved{0}, mCapacity{max_capacity()}, mFront{0}, mLength{0}
{
  if (alloc == other.mAllocator) {
    this->swap(other);
  } else {
    mAllocator = alloc;
    mCapacity = other.mCapacity;
    resizeIfRequired(other.mLength);
    for (size_type i = 0; i < other.size(); ++i) {
      push(std::move(other[i]));
    }
    other.reset();
    other.mCapacity = 0;
  }
}

/**
 * @param[in] other Queue to copy.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr gto::cqueue<T, Allocator> & gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::operator=(const cqueue &other) {
  if (this != &other) {
    cqueue tmp(other);
    this->swap(tmp);
  }
  return *this;
}

/**
 * @param[in] num Element position.
 * @return Index in buffer.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr typename gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::size_type gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::getUncheckedIndex(size_type pos) const noexcept {
  return ((mFront + pos) % (mReserved == 0 ? 1 : mReserved));
}

/**
 * @param[in] num Element position.
 * @return Index in buffer.
 * @exception std::out_of_range Invalid position.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr typename gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::size_type gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::getCheckedIndex(size_type pos) const noexcept(false) {
  if (pos >= mLength) {
    throw std::out_of_range("cqueue access out-of-range");
  } else {
    return getUncheckedIndex(pos);
  }
}

/**
 * @details Remove all elements.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
void gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::clear() noexcept {
  for (size_type i = 0; i < mLength; ++i) {
    size_type index = getUncheckedIndex(i);
    std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::destroy(mAllocator, mData + index);
  }
  mFront = 0;
  mLength = 0;
}

/**
 * @details Remove all elements and frees memory.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
void gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::reset() noexcept {
  clear();
  std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::deallocate(mAllocator, mData, mReserved);
  mData = nullptr;
  mReserved = 0;
}

/**
 * @details Swap content with another same-type cqueue.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr void gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::swap(cqueue &other) noexcept {
  if (this == &other) {
    return;
  }
  if constexpr (std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::propagate_on_container_swap::value) {
    std::swap(mAllocator, other.mAllocator);
  }
  std::swap(mData, other.mData);
  std::swap(mFront, other.mFront);
  std::swap(mLength, other.mLength);
  std::swap(mReserved, other.mReserved);
  std::swap(mCapacity, other.mCapacity);
}

/**
 * @brief Compute the new buffer size.
 * @param[in] n New queue size.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr typename gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::size_type gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::getNewMemoryLength(size_type n) const noexcept {
  size_type ret = (mReserved == 0 ? std::min(mCapacity, DEFAULT_RESERVED) : mReserved);
  while (ret < n) {
    ret *= GROWTH_FACTOR;
  }
  return std::min(ret, mCapacity);
}

/**
 * @param[in] n Expected future queue size.
 * @exception std::length_error Capacity exceeded.
 * @exception ... Error throwed by move contructors.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr void gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::resizeIfRequired(size_type n) {
  if (n < mReserved) {
    [[likely]]
    return;
  } else if (n > mCapacity) {
    [[unlikely]]    
    throw std::length_error("cqueue capacity exceeded");
  } else {
    size_type len = getNewMemoryLength(n);
    resize(len);
  }
}

/**
 * @param[in] n Expected future queue size.
 * @exception std::length_error Capacity exceeded.
 * @exception ... Error throwed by move contructors.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr void gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::reserve(size_type n) {
  if (n < mReserved) {
    return;
  } else if (n > mCapacity) {
    throw std::length_error("cqueue capacity exceeded");
  } else {
    resize(n);
  }
}

/**
 * @details Memory is not shrink if current length below DEFAULT_RESERVED.
 * @exception std::length_error Capacity exceeded.
 * @exception ... Error throwed by move contructors.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr void gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::shrink_to_fit() {
  if (mLength == 0 || mLength == mReserved || mLength <= DEFAULT_RESERVED) {
    return;
  } else {
    resize(mLength);
  }
}

/**
 * @param[in] n New reserved size.
 * @details Provides strong exception guarantee.
 * @see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/exceptions#Exception_safety
 * @exception ... Error throwed by move contructors.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
void gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::resize(size_type len)
{
  pointer tmp = std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::allocate(mAllocator, len);

  if constexpr (std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value) {
    // move elements from mData to tmp
    for (size_type i = 0; i < mLength; ++i) {
      size_type index = getUncheckedIndex(i);
      std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::construct(mAllocator, tmp + i, std::move(mData[index]));
    }
  }
  else {
    // copy elements from mData to tmp
    size_type i = 0;
    try {
      for (i = 0; i < mLength; ++i) {
        size_type index = getUncheckedIndex(i);
        std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::construct(mAllocator, tmp + i, mData[index]);
      }
    } catch (...) {
      for (size_type j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::destroy(mAllocator, tmp + j);
      }
      std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::deallocate(mAllocator, tmp, len);
      throw;
    }
  }

  // destroy mData elements
  for (size_type j = 0; j < mLength; ++j) {
    size_type index = getUncheckedIndex(j);
    std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::destroy(mAllocator, mData + index);
  }

  // deallocate mData
  std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::deallocate(mAllocator, mData, mReserved);

  // assign new content
  mData = tmp;
  mReserved = len;
  mFront = 0;
}

/**
 * @param[in] val Value to add.
 * @exception std::length_error Number of values exceed queue capacity.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr void gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::push(const T &val) {
  resizeIfRequired(mLength + 1);
  size_type index = getUncheckedIndex(mLength);
  std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::construct(mAllocator, mData + index, val);
  ++mLength;
}

/**
 * @param[in] val Value to add.
 * @exception std::length_error Number of values exceed queue capacity.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr void gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::push(T &&val) {
  resizeIfRequired(mLength + 1);
  size_type index = getUncheckedIndex(mLength);
  std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::construct(mAllocator, mData + index, std::move(val));
  ++mLength;
}

/**
 * @param[in] val Value to add.
 * @exception std::length_error Number of values exceed queue capacity.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr void gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::push_front(const T &val) {
  resizeIfRequired(mLength + 1);
  size_type index = (mLength == 0 ? 0 : (mFront == 0 ? mReserved : mFront) - 1);
  std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::construct(mAllocator, mData + index, val);
  mFront = index;
  ++mLength;
}

/**
 * @param[in] val Value to add.
 * @exception std::length_error Number of values exceed queue capacity.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr void gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::push_front(T &&val) {
  resizeIfRequired(mLength + 1);
  size_type index = (mLength == 0 ? 0 : (mFront == 0 ? mReserved : mFront) - 1);
  std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::construct(mAllocator, mData + index, std::move(val));
  mFront = index;
  ++mLength;
}

/**
 * @param[in] args Arguments of the new item.
 * @exception std::length_error Number of values exceed queue capacity.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
template <class... Args>
constexpr void gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::emplace(Args&&... args) {
  resizeIfRequired(mLength + 1);
  size_type index = getUncheckedIndex(mLength);
  std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::construct(mAllocator, mData + index, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  ++mLength;
}

/**
 * @return true = an element was erased, false = no elements in the queue.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr bool gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::pop() {
  if (mLength == 0) {
    return false;
  }
  std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::destroy(mAllocator, mData + mFront);
  mFront = getUncheckedIndex(1);
  --mLength;
  return true;
}

/**
 * @return true = an element was erased, false = no elements in the queue.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr bool gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::pop_back() {
  if (mLength == 0) {
    return false;
  }
  size_type index = getUncheckedIndex(mLength - 1);
  std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::destroy(mAllocator, mData + index);
  --mLength;
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Tests

I'm disappointed that you didn't include the tests in the review - that's usually the best way to see how the code is intended to behave, and to determine whether anything has been overlooked.  (I did, exceptionally, pull the the tests from your Git repo, but I obviously can't comment on them as they are not in the review).

---

## Iterators

Looking through the interface, I see that there are completely separate parallel implementations of `iterator` and `const_iterator`.  It's possible to use a single implementation for these; the one tricky part is that bit that's currently missing - implicit conversion from `iterator` to `const_iterator` - we'll need constraints to ensure that appears in only the one class.

The size comparison operators can be reduced to a single `<=>` (provided your target supports all of C++20).

The addition and subtraction operators only test for overflow in one direction, and ignore overflow when adding or subtracting negative values.  We can use `std::clamp()` for constraining the result (and in the constructor).

Consider using `[[nodiscard]]` on the post-increment operators to encourage use of the more efficient pre-increment operators where the result isn't needed.

With those changes, I arrived at

```
private:
    template<typename U>
    class iter {
      public:
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
        using value_type = U;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using pointer = value_type *;
        using reference = value_type &;
      private:
        friend class iter<std::add_const_t<value_type>>;
        using size_type = std::size_t;
        using queue_type = std::conditional_t<std::is_const_v<value_type>,
                                              const cqueue, cqueue>;

        queue_type *queue = nullptr;
        difference_type pos = 0;

        auto cast(difference_type n) const {
            return (n < 0 ? queue->size() : static_cast<size_type>(n));
        }
        auto size() const {
            return static_cast<difference_type>(queue->size());
        }
        auto clamp(difference_type p) const {
            return std::clamp<difference_type>(p, -1, size());
        }
      public:
        explicit iter(queue_type *o, difference_type p = 0)
            : queue{o},
              pos{clamp(p)}
        {}
        iter(const iter<std::remove_const_t<value_type>>& other)
            requires std::is_const_v<value_type>
            : queue{other.queue},
              pos{other.pos}
        {}
        iter(const iter<value_type>& other) = default;

        reference operator*() { return queue->operator[](cast(pos)); }
        pointer operator->() { return &(queue->operator[](cast(pos))); }
        reference operator[](difference_type rhs) const {
            return queue->operator[](cast(pos + rhs));
        }

        auto operator<=>(const iter &rhs) const {
            return queue == rhs.queue ? pos <=> rhs.pos : std::partial_ordering::unordered;
        }
        iter& operator++() { return *this += 1; }
        iter& operator--() { return *this += -1; }
        [[nodiscard]] iter operator++(int) { iter tmp{queue, pos}; ++*this; return tmp; }
        [[nodiscard]] iter operator--(int) { iter tmp{queue, pos}; --*this; return tmp; }
        auto& operator+=(difference_type rhs) { pos = clamp(pos + rhs); return *this; }
        auto& operator-=(difference_type rhs) { pos = clamp(pos - rhs); return *this; }
        auto operator+(difference_type rhs) const { return iter{queue, pos + rhs}; }
        auto operator-(difference_type rhs) const { return iter{queue, pos - rhs}; }
        friend iter operator+(difference_type lhs, const iter &rhs) { return iter{rhs.queue, lhs + rhs.pos}; }
        friend iter operator-(difference_type lhs, const iter &rhs) { return iter{rhs.queue, lhs - rhs.pos}; }
        auto operator-(const iter &rhs) const { return pos - rhs.pos; }
    };
```

```
public:
    using iterator = iter<T>;
    using const_iterator = iter<const T>;
```

---

## Queue interface

We seem to have a mix of snake_case and camelCase identifiers.  Prefer to stick with a single convention - since this looks like a standard container, I recommend snake_case to match the standard container functions.

I don't think `[[nodiscard]]` adds value anywhere you've used it.  All those functions are idempotent, and the discarded value can be recomputed at any time.  Prefer to reserve this attribute for functions where ignoring the result will lead to program misbehaviour (the canonical example is `std::scanf()` - the return value is the only way to know whether the pointers were written to, and there's no way to recover that information if it's ignored).

Consider adding `cbegin()` and `cend()` and also the reversed begin/end iterator functions.

It's a good idea to initialise all fields, even if default initialisation will do what we want.  For example:

> ```
>     constexpr cqueue(cqueue &&other) noexcept { this->swap(other); }
> ```

`g++ -Weffc++` wants us to initialise `mAllocator` in this constructor.  That's easily done using a default initialiser:

```
    allocator_type mAllocator = {};
```

I don't think we need to overload functions such as `push()` - if we accept our argument by value, then `std::move()` it into place, we should be able to avoid unnecessary copies:

```
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr void gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::push(T val) {
  resizeIfRequired(mLength + 1);
  size_type index = getUncheckedIndex(mLength);
  std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::construct(mAllocator, mData + index, std::move(val));
  ++mLength;
}
```

We're missing a public `resize()`, but have a private `resize()` that does something different from standard containers' `resize()`.  I suggest renaming this, and possibly implementing the expected `resize()`.

---

## Implementation (general)

I see we're using `std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>` quite a lot in the implementation; it probably makes sense to make a private alias for this.

---

## Constructors

We have quite a lot of duplication.  For example:

> ```
> /**
>  * @param[in] other Queue to copy.
>  */
> template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
> constexpr gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::cqueue(const cqueue &other) :
>     mAllocator{std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::select_on_container_copy_construction(other.get_allocator())},
>     mData{nullptr}, mReserved{0}, mCapacity{other.mCapacity}, mFront{0}, mLength{0}
> {
>   resizeIfRequired(other.mLength);
>   for (size_type i = 0; i < other.size(); ++i) {
>     push(other[i]);
>   }
> }
>
> /**
>  * @param[in] other Queue to copy.
>  * @param[in] alloc Allocator to use.
>  */
> template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
> constexpr gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::cqueue(const cqueue &other, const_alloc_reference alloc) : 
>     mAllocator{alloc}, mData{nullptr}, mReserved{0}, mCapacity{other.mCapacity}, mFront{0}, mLength{0}
> {
>   resizeIfRequired(other.mLength);
>   for (size_type i = 0; i < other.size(); ++i) {
>     push(other[i]);
>   }
> }
> ```

Instead of writing out that body twice, one constructor can simply forward to the other:

```
/**
 * @param[in] other Queue to copy.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::cqueue(const cqueue &other)
    : cqueue{other, allocator_traits::select_on_container_copy_construction(other.get_allocator())}
{
}

/**
 * @param[in] other Queue to copy.
 * @param[in] alloc Allocator to use.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::cqueue(const cqueue &other, const_alloc_reference alloc) :
    mAllocator{alloc}, mCapacity{other.mCapacity}
{
  resizeIfRequired(other.mLength);
  for (size_type i = 0; i < other.size(); ++i) {
    push(other[i]);
  }
}
```

(I've also omitted the initialisers that duplicate the in-class initialisers, as they are just clutter).

It would be nice if the move-constructor, when moving from one allocator to another, could reduce its memory overheads.  I don't think this is possible whilst retaining the strong exception guarantee, though.  If we can't, we could at least reduce duplication, by copy-construct and swap:

```
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::cqueue(cqueue &&other, const_alloc_reference alloc)
{
  if (alloc == other.mAllocator) {
      swap(other);
  } else {
      cqueue q{other, alloc};
      swap(q);
      cqueue{std::move(other)}; // clear the source queue
  }
}
```

(That final clearing of source was needed to make the test pass - that might be over-testing, since we should only care that the moved-from object is sufficiently valid to be destructed).

---

## Member functions

Because `operator=()` uses copy-and-swap, there's no need to test for self-assignment:

```
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr auto gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::operator=(const cqueue &other) -> cqueue&
{
    cqueue tmp(other);
    swap(tmp);
    return *this;
}
```

Similarly, `swap()` itself functions perfectly well for self-swap, so we can eliminate the condition there.

Note also that the trailing return type allows us to use a simpler name; that becomes especially valuable for those functions returning a `size_type`.

If an exception is thrown in `resize()`, we should destruct the objects so far in reverse order of construction, but we're doing it in forward order.  I don't know if this ever makes a practical difference, but it's not hard to change.  Consider using a smart pointer for the storage, to reduce the cleanup we need in the `catch` clause:

```
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
void gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::resize(size_type len)
{
    auto const deleter = [&](value_type* p){ allocator_traits::deallocate(mAllocator, p, len); };
    std::unique_ptr<value_type, decltype(deleter)> utmp{allocator_traits::allocate(mAllocator, len), deleter};
    auto *const tmp = utmp.get();

  ⋮

  // deallocate mData
  allocator_traits::deallocate(mAllocator, mData, mReserved);

  // assign new content
  mData = utmp.release();
  mReserved = len;
  mFront = 0;
}
```

---

## Modified code

Sorry my indentation differs from the original; I didn't bother reconfiguring my editor from its usual settings.

````
#include <memory>
#include <limits>
#include <utility>
#include <concepts>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace gto {

/**
 * @brief Circular queue.
 * @details Iterators are invalidated by:
 *          push(), push_front(), emplace(), pop(), pop_back(), reserve(),
 *          shrink_to_fit(), reset() and clear().
 * @see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer
 * @see https://github.com/torrentg/cqueue
 * @note This class is not thread-safe.
 * @version 1.1.0
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
class cqueue {

    template<typename U>
    class iter {
      public:
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
        using value_type = U;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using pointer = value_type *;
        using reference = value_type &;
      private:
        friend class iter<std::add_const_t<value_type>>;
        using size_type = std::size_t;
        using queue_type = std::conditional_t<std::is_const_v<value_type>,
                                              const cqueue, cqueue>;

        queue_type *queue = nullptr;
        difference_type pos = 0;

        auto cast(difference_type n) const {
            return (n < 0 ? queue->size() : static_cast<size_type>(n));
        }
        auto size() const {
            return static_cast<difference_type>(queue->size());
        }
        auto clamp(difference_type p) const {
            return std::clamp<difference_type>(p, -1, size());
        }
      public:
        explicit iter(queue_type *o, difference_type p = 0)
            : queue{o},
              pos{clamp(p)}
        {}
        iter(const iter<std::remove_const_t<value_type>>& other)
            requires std::is_const_v<value_type>
            : queue{other.queue},
              pos{other.pos}
        {}
        iter(const iter<value_type>& other) = default;

        reference operator*() { return queue->operator[](cast(pos)); }
        pointer operator->() { return &(queue->operator[](cast(pos))); }
        reference operator[](difference_type rhs) const {
            return queue->operator[](cast(pos + rhs));
        }

        auto operator<=>(const iter &rhs) const {
            return queue == rhs.queue ? pos <=> rhs.pos : std::partial_ordering::unordered;
        }
        auto operator==(const iter &rhs) const { return *this <=> rhs == 0; }
        iter& operator++() { return *this += 1; }
        iter& operator--() { return *this += -1; }
        [[nodiscard]] iter operator++(int) { iter tmp{queue, pos}; ++*this; return tmp; }
        [[nodiscard]] iter operator--(int) { iter tmp{queue, pos}; --*this; return tmp; }
        auto& operator+=(difference_type rhs) { pos = clamp(pos + rhs); return *this; }
        auto& operator-=(difference_type rhs) { pos = clamp(pos - rhs); return *this; }
        auto operator+(difference_type rhs) const { return iter{queue, pos + rhs}; }
        auto operator-(difference_type rhs) const { return iter{queue, pos - rhs}; }
        friend iter operator+(difference_type lhs, const iter &rhs) { return iter{rhs.queue, lhs + rhs.pos}; }
        friend iter operator-(difference_type lhs, const iter &rhs) { return iter{rhs.queue, lhs - rhs.pos}; }
        auto operator-(const iter &rhs) const { return pos - rhs.pos; }
    };

  public: // declarations

    // Aliases
    using value_type = T;
    using reference = value_type &;
    using const_reference = const value_type &;
    using pointer = T *;
    using const_pointer = const pointer;
    using size_type = std::size_t;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using allocator_type = Allocator;
    using const_alloc_reference = const allocator_type &;

    using iterator = iter<T>;
    using const_iterator = iter<const T>;

  private: // declarations
    using allocator_traits = std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>;

  private: // static members

    //! Capacity increase factor.
    static constexpr size_type GROWTH_FACTOR = 2;
    //! Default initial capacity (power of 2).
    static constexpr size_type DEFAULT_RESERVED = 8;

  private: // members

    //! Memory allocator.
    [[no_unique_address]]
    allocator_type mAllocator = {};
    //! Buffer.
    pointer mData = nullptr;
    //! Buffer size.
    size_type mReserved = 0;
    //! Maximum number of elements (always > 0).
    size_type mCapacity = 0;
    //! Index representing first entry (0 <= mFront < mReserved).
    size_type mFront = 0;
    //! Number of entries in the queue (empty = 0, full = mReserved).
    size_type mLength = 0;

  private: // methods

    //! Convert from pos to index (throw exception if out-of-bounds).
    constexpr size_type getCheckedIndex(size_type pos) const noexcept(false);
    //! Convert from pos to index.
    constexpr size_type getUncheckedIndex(size_type pos) const noexcept;
    //! Compute memory size to reserve.
    constexpr size_type getNewMemoryLength(size_type n) const noexcept;
    //! Resize buffer.
    constexpr void resizeIfRequired(size_type n);
    //! Resize buffer.
    void resize(size_type n);
    //! Clear and dealloc memory (preserve capacity and allocator).
    void reset() noexcept;

  public: // static methods

    //! Maximum capacity the container is able to hold.
    static constexpr size_type max_capacity() noexcept { return (std::numeric_limits<difference_type>::max()); }

  public: // methods

    //! Constructor.
    constexpr explicit cqueue(const_alloc_reference alloc = Allocator()) : cqueue(0, alloc) {}
    //! Constructor (capacity=0 means unlimited).
    constexpr explicit cqueue(size_type capacity, const_alloc_reference alloc = Allocator());
    //! Copy constructor.
    constexpr cqueue(const cqueue &other);
    //! Copy constructor with allocator.
    constexpr cqueue(const cqueue &other, const_alloc_reference alloc);
    //! Move constructor.
    constexpr cqueue(cqueue &&other) noexcept { this->swap(other); }
    //! Move constructor.
    constexpr cqueue(cqueue &&other, const_alloc_reference alloc);
    //! Destructor.
    ~cqueue() noexcept { reset(); };

    //! Copy assignment.
    constexpr cqueue & operator=(const cqueue &other);
    //! Move assignment.
    constexpr cqueue & operator=(cqueue &&other) { this->swap(other); return *this; }

    //! Return container allocator.
    constexpr allocator_type get_allocator() const noexcept { return mAllocator; }
    //! Return queue capacity.
    constexpr size_type capacity() const noexcept { return (mCapacity == max_capacity() ? 0 : mCapacity); }
    //! Return the number of items.
    constexpr size_type size() const noexcept { return mLength; }
    //! Current reserved size (numbers of items).
    constexpr size_type reserved() const noexcept { return mReserved; }
    //! Check if there are items in the queue.
    constexpr bool empty() const noexcept { return (mLength == 0); }

    //! Return the first element.
    constexpr const_reference front() const { return operator[](0); }
    //! Return the first element.
    constexpr reference front() { return operator[](0); }
    //! Return the last element.
    constexpr const_reference back() const { return operator[](mLength-1); }
    //! Return the last element.
    constexpr reference back() { return operator[](mLength-1); }

    //! Insert an element at the end.
    constexpr void push(T val);
    //! Insert an element at the front.
    constexpr void push_front(const T &val);
    //! Insert an element at the front.
    constexpr void push_front(T &&val);

    //! Construct and insert an element at the end.
    template <class... Args>
    constexpr void emplace(Args&&... args);
    //! Remove the front element.
    constexpr bool pop();
    //! Remove the back element.
    constexpr bool pop_back();

    //! Returns a reference to the element at position n.
    constexpr reference operator[](size_type n) { return mData[getCheckedIndex(n)]; }
    //! Returns a const reference to the element at position n.
    constexpr const_reference operator[](size_type n) const { return mData[getCheckedIndex(n)]; }

    //! Returns an iterator to the first element.
    constexpr iterator begin() noexcept { return iterator(this, 0); }
    //! Returns an iterator to the element following the last element.
    constexpr iterator end() noexcept { return iterator(this, static_cast<difference_type>(size())); }
    //! Returns an iterator to the first element.
    constexpr const_iterator begin() const noexcept { return const_iterator(this, 0); }
    //! Returns an iterator to the element following the last element.
    constexpr const_iterator end() const noexcept { return const_iterator(this, static_cast<difference_type>(size())); }

    //! Clear content.
    void clear() noexcept;
    //! Swap content.
    constexpr void swap (cqueue &x) noexcept;
    //! Ensure buffer size.
    constexpr void reserve(size_type n);
    //! Shrink reserved memory to current size.
    constexpr void shrink_to_fit();
};

} // namespace gto

/**
 * @param[in] capacity Container capacity.
 * @param[in] alloc Allocator to use.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::cqueue(size_type capacity, const_alloc_reference alloc) :
    mAllocator(alloc), mCapacity{capacity == 0 ? max_capacity() : capacity}
{
  if (capacity > max_capacity()) {
    throw std::length_error("cqueue max capacity exceeded");
  }
}

/**
 * @param[in] other Queue to copy.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::cqueue(const cqueue &other)
    : cqueue{other, allocator_traits::select_on_container_copy_construction(other.get_allocator())}
{
}

/**
 * @param[in] other Queue to copy.
 * @param[in] alloc Allocator to use.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::cqueue(const cqueue &other, const_alloc_reference alloc) :
    mAllocator{alloc}, mCapacity{other.mCapacity}
{
  resizeIfRequired(other.mLength);
  for (size_type i = 0; i < other.size(); ++i) {
    push(other[i]);
  }
}

/**
 * @param[in] other Queue to copy.
 * @param[in] alloc Allocator to use
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::cqueue(cqueue &&other, const_alloc_reference alloc)
{
  if (alloc == other.mAllocator) {
      swap(other);
  } else {
      cqueue q{other, alloc};
      swap(q);
      cqueue{std::move(other)}; // clear the source queue
  }
}

/**
 * @param[in] other Queue to copy.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr auto gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::operator=(const cqueue &other) -> cqueue&
{
    cqueue tmp(other);
    swap(tmp);
    return *this;
}

/**
 * @param[in] num Element position.
 * @return Index in buffer.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr auto gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::getUncheckedIndex(size_type pos) const noexcept -> size_type
{
    return (mFront + pos) % (mReserved == 0 ? 1 : mReserved);
}

/**
 * @param[in] num Element position.
 * @return Index in buffer.
 * @exception std::out_of_range Invalid position.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr auto gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::getCheckedIndex(size_type pos) const noexcept(false) -> size_type
{
  if (pos >= mLength) {
    throw std::out_of_range("cqueue access out-of-range");
  }
  return getUncheckedIndex(pos);
}

/**
 * @details Remove all elements.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
void gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::clear() noexcept {
  for (size_type i = 0; i < mLength; ++i) {
    size_type index = getUncheckedIndex(i);
    allocator_traits::destroy(mAllocator, mData + index);
  }
  mFront = 0;
  mLength = 0;
}

/**
 * @details Remove all elements and frees memory.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
void gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::reset() noexcept {
  clear();
  allocator_traits::deallocate(mAllocator, mData, mReserved);
  mData = nullptr;
  mReserved = 0;
}

/**
 * @details Swap content with another same-type cqueue.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr void gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::swap(cqueue &other) noexcept {
  if constexpr (allocator_traits::propagate_on_container_swap::value) {
    std::swap(mAllocator, other.mAllocator);
  }
  std::swap(mData, other.mData);
  std::swap(mFront, other.mFront);
  std::swap(mLength, other.mLength);
  std::swap(mReserved, other.mReserved);
  std::swap(mCapacity, other.mCapacity);
}

/**
 * @brief Compute the new buffer size.
 * @param[in] n New queue size.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr auto gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::getNewMemoryLength(size_type n) const noexcept -> size_type
{
  size_type ret = (mReserved == 0 ? std::min(mCapacity, DEFAULT_RESERVED) : mReserved);
  while (ret < n) {
    ret *= GROWTH_FACTOR;
  }
  return std::min(ret, mCapacity);
}

/**
 * @param[in] n Expected future queue size.
 * @exception std::length_error Capacity exceeded.
 * @exception ... Error throwed by move contructors.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr void gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::resizeIfRequired(size_type n) noexcept(false) {
  if (n < mReserved) {
    [[likely]]
    return;
  } else if (n > mCapacity) {
    [[unlikely]]
    throw std::length_error("cqueue capacity exceeded");
  } else {
    size_type len = getNewMemoryLength(n);
    resize(len);
  }
}

/**
 * @param[in] n Expected future queue size.
 * @exception std::length_error Capacity exceeded.
 * @exception ... Error throwed by move contructors.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr void gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::reserve(size_type n) {
  if (n < mReserved) {
    return;
  } else if (n > mCapacity) {
    throw std::length_error("cqueue capacity exceeded");
  } else {
    resize(n);
  }
}

/**
 * @details Memory is not shrink if current length below DEFAULT_RESERVED.
 * @exception std::length_error Capacity exceeded.
 * @exception ... Error throwed by move contructors.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr void gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::shrink_to_fit() {
  if (mLength == 0 || mLength == mReserved || mLength <= DEFAULT_RESERVED) {
    return;
  } else {
    resize(mLength);
  }
}

/**
 * @param[in] n New reserved size.
 * @details Provides strong exception guarantee.
 * @see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/exceptions#Exception_safety
 * @exception ... Error throwed by move contructors.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
void gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::resize(size_type len)
{
    auto const deleter = [&](value_type* p){ allocator_traits::deallocate(mAllocator, p, len); };
    std::unique_ptr<value_type, decltype(deleter)> utmp{allocator_traits::allocate(mAllocator, len), deleter};
    auto *const tmp = utmp.get();

  if constexpr (std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value) {
    // move elements from mData to tmp
    for (size_type i = 0; i < mLength; ++i) {
      size_type index = getUncheckedIndex(i);
      allocator_traits::construct(mAllocator, tmp + i, std::move(mData[index]));
    }
  }
  else {
    // copy elements from mData to tmp
    size_type i = 0;
    try {
      for (i = 0; i < mLength; ++i) {
        size_type index = getUncheckedIndex(i);
        allocator_traits::construct(mAllocator, tmp + i, mData[index]);
      }
    } catch (...) {
      while (i-- > 0) {
        allocator_traits::destroy(mAllocator, tmp + i);
      }
      throw;
    }
  }

  // destroy mData elements
  for (size_type j = 0; j < mLength; ++j) {
    size_type index = getUncheckedIndex(j);
    allocator_traits::destroy(mAllocator, mData + index);
  }

  // deallocate mData
  allocator_traits::deallocate(mAllocator, mData, mReserved);

  // assign new content
  mData = utmp.release();
  mReserved = len;
  mFront = 0;
}

/**
 * @param[in] val Value to add.
 * @exception std::length_error Number of values exceed queue capacity.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr void gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::push(T val) {
  resizeIfRequired(mLength + 1);
  size_type index = getUncheckedIndex(mLength);
  allocator_traits::construct(mAllocator, mData + index, std::move(val));
  ++mLength;
}

/**
 * @param[in] val Value to add.
 * @exception std::length_error Number of values exceed queue capacity.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr void gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::push_front(T val) {
  resizeIfRequired(mLength + 1);
  size_type index = (mLength == 0 ? 0 : (mFront == 0 ? mReserved : mFront) - 1);
  allocator_traits::construct(mAllocator, mData + index, std::move(val));
  mFront = index;
  ++mLength;
}

/**
 * @param[in] args Arguments of the new item.
 * @exception std::length_error Number of values exceed queue capacity.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
template <class... Args>
constexpr void gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::emplace(Args&&... args) {
  resizeIfRequired(mLength + 1);
  size_type index = getUncheckedIndex(mLength);
  allocator_traits::construct(mAllocator, mData + index, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  ++mLength;
}

/**
 * @return true = an element was erased, false = no elements in the queue.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr bool gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::pop() {
  if (mLength == 0) {
    return false;
  }
  allocator_traits::destroy(mAllocator, mData + mFront);
  mFront = getUncheckedIndex(1);
  --mLength;
  return true;
}

/**
 * @return true = an element was erased, false = no elements in the queue.
 */
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr bool gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::pop_back() {
  if (mLength == 0) {
    return false;
  }
  size_type index = getUncheckedIndex(mLength - 1);
  allocator_traits::destroy(mAllocator, mData + index);
  --mLength;
  return true;
}
```
````

Comment: Thank you very much for your code review.
I'm learning a lot.

Answer (score 6):

## Unnecessary initialization in the definition of the constructors

You don't need to explicitly initialize member variables in the constructors that already use member value initialization, or that you are going to overwrite in the body of the constructor. So I would just write:

```
template<std::copyable T, typename Allocator>
constexpr gto::cqueue<T, Allocator>::cqueue(size_type capacity, const_alloc_reference alloc)
    : mAllocator(alloc)
{
    if (capacity > max_capacity()) {
        throw std::length_error("cqueue max capacity exceeded");
    } else {
        mCapacity = (capacity == 0 ? max_capacity() : capacity);
    }
}
```

## Make `max_capacity` a constant instead of a function

Since `std::numeric_limits::max()` is `constexpr`, you can use it to initialize a `static constexpr` variable:

```
static constexpr size_type MAX_CAPACITY = std::numeric_limits<difference_type>::max();
```

This way it really looks and acts like the constant that it is.

## Let `emplace()` and `push()` return a `reference`

Since C++17, the STL containers' `emplace()` and `push()` functions return a reference to the item you just inserted. Consider adding the same feature.

## Add both `_front()` and `_back()` versions

Your interface is a bit inconsistent; there is `push()` and `push_front()`, but only `emplace()`. I would also expect an `emplace_front()`, and to avoid any confusion, rename `push()` to `push_back()` and `emplace()` to `emplace_back()`. This will also be consistent with STL containers that allow pushing from both ends, and the closer you follow the STL's conventions, the more algorithms (that work on, say, `std::deque`) will be able to work on your circular queue.

Note that some STL containers have an `insert()` member function that allow you to insert an element in the middle of the container, they then also provide an `emplace()` variant of that, but it is distinguished by having a position argument (see for example [`std::deque::emplace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/emplace)).

## Inconsistent reserving/shrinking behavior

There is a `DEFAULT_RESERVED`, but the constructor doesn't reserve anything, it's only when adding elements or shrinking that `DEFAULT_RESERVED` comes into play. If at construction time the queue can have no allocation, then I would expect that if all elements are removed and `shrink_to_fit()` is called, the queue would be in that same exact state: nothing allocated. However, it seems the intention is to not shrink to below `DEFAULT_RESERVED`, but the logic is wrong: it will just not shrink at all if there are less than `DEFAULT_RESERVED` elements in the queue (`mLength`), even if you have a huge amount of memory reserved (`mReserved`)!

Also, `shrink_to_fit()` may or may not change the size of the container, but in the STL, this function is only meant to change the capacity. So it should not call `resize()`, but you should rather implement a `change_capacity()` function that does the change in allocation, and have both `shrink_to_fit()` and `resize()` call that.

Since you do allow nothing to be allocated, I would rename `DEFAULT_RESERVED` to `MIN_ALLOCATE`, to make it clear that this is the minimum number of elements used when *allocating* memory. That's exactly what `getNewMemoryLength()` does.

## `resize()` doesn't work like the one from the STL

For STL containers, calling [`resize()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) with a number larger than the current size will actually cause new elements to be constructed. You'll also notice that it has overloads that take a `value_type` parameter so the new elements can have a value other than the default constructed one.

Now, for your circular queue, "size" has a different meaning: it's the *maximum* size of the queue. Consider whether you need a maximum size to begin with; your container would still work pretty much the same if the maximum size was just `max_capacity` from the beginning, with the only exception being that `push()` and `emplace()` wouldn't `throw` if you push and its capacity was already full.

Apart from that, consider whether you want to match the STL terminology, which means you might give your `resize()` a different name, or whether you want to be inconsistent with the STL. It will probably come as no surprise that I would recommend the former.

## Pay better attention to edge cases

In `reserve()`, you check if `n < mReserved`, if so you return early. This is good, but what if `n == mReserved`? You could have returned early here as well. Now you will call `resize()`, which will not bother to check whether it can avoid allocating new memory, so it will cause the whole queue to be copied for no good reason.

Also consider that `resize()` could be called with size `0`. Did you consider whether that would be handled correctly? Is calling `allocate(mAllocator, 0)` valid? Does the rest of your code handle it correctly if `mData` is not `nullptr` but `mReserved` is zero? It does, but if you weren't sure about this, remember to pay more attention to this in the future.

What if the size of the queue is equal to `max_capacity`? Consider that `pos + 1 < size()` is unsafe when `pos == max_capacity`, since [signed integer overflow has undefined behavior in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188263/is-signed-integer-overflow-still-undefined-behavior-in-c). Write the safer `pos == size() ? size() : pos + 1`.

## Create a type alias for the allocator traits

Having to type `std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>` all the time is a lot of work and it clutters the code. Consider creating a type alias for it:

```
private:
    using allocator_traits = std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>;
```

Comment: I noticed you post this whilst I was writing my review, but didn't read it until after. Once again, we have a large overlap in our observations (even down to picking the same `allocator_traits` name), but you picked up a few that I missed.  This is a great review, as usual.

Comment: And now you made exactly the edit (missing "when") I was about to make!  Are you reading my mind?

Comment: Don't tell anyone, they wouldn't believe it anyway! But thanks :) And you make lots of good points as well I missed, like the need for test cases, and the improvements for the iterators.

Comment: Thank you very much for your accurate code review. 
It is a serious error that of function shrink_to_fit! 
Double error since it was not identified in the unit tests either.